# How to install .bar file in Blackberry 10 simulator

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-10

I have 1 .bar file which is generated from eclipse plug-in.

Now I want to test that .bar file in Blackberry 10 simulator.

How can I test that Application?

I have installed blackberry simulator 10 Dev Alpha successfully and configured IP Address also.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the playbook simulator working using this tut:

http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2012/02/07/getting-started-with-phonegap-on-blackberry-playbook/

Comment: @jon..so are you able to run .bar file on your play book?

Comment: to be honest I cant remember, its been a while since I was dev for bb.  Come to think of it probably not as I think I would simulate from command, and then publish bar when done....  Is there a specific issue with doing it this way that you need to test the bar

Comment: @Jon...Thanks for reply..Actually Application is made for Android..I had converted it to .bar file using online tool so I can run that same application on BB Simulator 10. I tried it..I can see Application icon in BB simulator but now it is not working..so..Anyway Thanks...

Comment: cool.  BB keep giving free stuff away for apps.  so I hope you get some cool stuff from them!!

Answer (score 8):

After signing the bar file please paste the following line into the command line 
*

> blackberry-deploy -installApp 192.168.177.131 -password 1234 hello.bar

*

Answer (score 1):

When you say you're using the Eclipse plug in, do you mean the QNX Momentics IDE (which is The native BlackBerry 10 IDE but based on Eclipse)? If so, here are the steps I take.

If you have the simulator running, make sure development mode is on.

Click the Run Menu -> Run Configurations
Select "Simulator-Debug" for the run configuration (note the simulator needs to run the x86 compiled binary not ARM)
You mention that you have the IP address set up, so the simulator should appear as a target.

I also like to set the auto build option.

Apply these settings and close.

Now run and the IDE should build the code, and deploy it to your simulator.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have only the .bar you can use the vnBB10 tool to install the app in the device or simulator. http://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-10-os-f269/how-get-bb10-hardware-id-sideload-app-bar-file-into-blackberry-10-a-780773/

Comment: the link is invalid. Can you please tell me what is the process of it